# Are the SharePoint services a web services or windows services?

Tags: spservices

Are the SharePoint services a web services or windows services? please provide me with references

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SharePoint services, the problem with answering this question lies in the word 'the'. SharePoint is a big application or rather a mix of several applications. Thus it supplies both Web/WCF Services like the ones that the Client object Model uses it supplies REST services which is also web based. 
But it also has several windows based services like the Timer Service and the search services.
So the answer is both.

Answer (score 1):

[SharePoint 2010 **Web** Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx) uses Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) over HTTP and acts as a communications interface between client programs and SharePoint.

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is a [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) which abstracts SharePoint's Web Services and makes them easier to use.